# SQL Server Security Access Issue after Password Change

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an application which reads from SQL Server but I have noticed an issue if the user has to do a password reset for there system.

In Sql Server I have created a Login for the database with a password that never expires and gives read / write access to the database only.

In VB net the connection string reads

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Security Login;Password=Security Password
```

The users have 2 logins, 1 is into the WYSE Terminal itself and then Login for the Citrix Farm

They need to be logged into Citrix farm for access to the Network drive to run he software.

If the Users does a password reset then the application for some reason is unable to read/write to/from the server for at least 12 hrs.

The application requires no login, it just has its own connection to the database.

Any ideas

Comment: Does the database connection fail? Add the full error details to your question.

Comment: It seems the error occurs when they try and do the install from the published application, error states .net Error "Login failed for User ".this user is not associated with a trusted SQL server

Comment: I suspect caching of client credentials if nothing other than trying later resolves the issue. Logging out completely and back in should resolve the issue.  I'm not particularly familiar with Citrix so there could be additional considerations about refreshing the cache.

Comment: Something is not working as you explained. At some point your application is using a connectionstring with  integrated security, trying to login to the database server using the user login instead of the application login. 

You can notice this by the error message you explained, "Error "Login failed for User ".this user is not associated with a trusted SQL server" .

Besides this problem, you also seems to have some synchronization problem in your active directory, creating the 12 hours problem.

Comment: In the connection string I have replaced 'Persist Security Info=True' with 'trusted_connection = true'.so far touch wood I have had no other reports or same error, I just find it peculiar that this would happen after a password change, when my connection string does not rely on AD credentials to connect, PS its SQL Server 2005 and VB 2010 if that makes a difference